# Span element's content doesn't change

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress

I'm working on a WordPress website for my client, and WordPress always requires some small custom adjustments here and there. To avoid relying on plugins to solve everything, I decided I'd finally give JavaScript the attention it deserves and learn how to use it to make the necessary tweaks. And it's going well so far! But I think I hit a wall on a particular thing. Let me elaborate:

There's a button on my page, with the goal of loading more blog snippets than the page already shows. This button is a styled anchor tag with no href attribute set and a span tag inside, said span containing the button's text.Here's the code:

```html
<nav class="vlt-pagination vlt-pagination--load-more">
    <a href="#" class="vlt-btn vlt-btn--primary">
        <i class="icofont icofont-spinner icofont-rotate"></i>
        <span>Load More</span>
        ::after
    </a>
</nav>
```

My goal is to change the destination URL to the actual blog page and also change the button text, using Javascript only.

Half of it is done. I managed to change the link by using setAttribute(). Works like a charm so far:

```js
var posts_button_container = document.getElementsByClassName("vlt-pagination")[0];
var posts_button = posts_button_container.firstChild;
posts_button.setAttribute("href","http://localhost/coan/blog/");
```

The wall I hit was that I simply couldn't change the content of the span afterwards. Here's the code I came up with:

```js
var button_text = posts_button.getElementsByTagName("SPAN")[0];
button_text.innerText = "Leia mais";
```

I tried variations of this code using .innerHTML and .textContent to no avail. I tried console.log(button_text), to see what kind of element the function was getting. Turns out it outputs a blank message on console.

I'm new to Javascript, which means I might be looking past something really basic, but at the moment I can't understand what I did wrong here. I appreciate every insight you guys can give me on how to change the text of this span!

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this with:

```
const anchor = document.querySelector('a.vlt-btn');
anchor.href = 'http://localhost/coan/blog/';
anchor.querySelector('span').innerHTML = 'Leia mais';
```

The href attribute can be read and set with the .href property so you dont need setAttribute in this case.

I hope this helps

Comment: It worked like a charm! Probably my mistake was thinking I needed to get the span as a child node of the anchor only then to proceed changing its innerText. Turns out by changing the anchor's innerText directly, it would already do the job. You blew a rookie's mind! xD Thanks a lot, mate, it was exactly what I needed.